# how to make QSortFilterProxyModel faster

Tags: c++, qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have trouble with making my QSortFilterProxyModel (which is connected to an sqlite database) fast. Everything is okay when the database is close to empty, but as the rows increase, the model starts to become very slow in searching. I read [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-40471.html) that you can cache results to make the searching faster, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Can anyone suggest and explain methods on how i could make searching faster?

The code below shows how I reimplemented the class. Please note that I had to reimplement QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow() function to allow the proxy model to filter multiple columns simultaneously (code i got from somewhere else....heeeheeeheee).

```
CustomProxyModel::CustomProxyModel(QObject *parent) :
flag(Default),
QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
}

CustomProxyModel::CustomProxyModel(FilterFlag flag, QObject *parent) :
flag(flag),
QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
}

void CustomProxyModel::setFilterKeyColumns(const QList<qint32> &filterColumns) {
    m_columnPatterns.clear();

    foreach(qint32 column, filterColumns) {
        m_columnPatterns.insert(column, qMakePair(QString(), Default));
    }
}

void CustomProxyModel::addFilterFixedString(qint32 column, const QString &pattern,        FilterFlag flag) {
    if(!m_columnPatterns.contains(column))
        return;

    m_columnPatterns[column] = qMakePair(pattern, flag);
    recalculateFilter(pattern);

    invalidateFilter();
}

void CustomProxyModel::setFilterKeyColumn(int column) {
    m_columnPatterns.clear();

    QSortFilterProxyModel::setFilterKeyColumn(column);
}

void CustomProxyModel::setFilterFixedString(const QString &pattern, FilterFlag flag) {
    filterFixedString = pattern;
    setFilterFlag(flag);
    recalculateFilter(pattern);

    invalidateFilter();
}

void CustomProxyModel::setFilterRegExp(const QString &pattern, FilterFlag flag) {
    setFilterFlag(flag);
    QSortFilterProxyModel::setFilterRegExp(pattern);
}

void CustomProxyModel::setFilterRegExp(const QRegExp &regExp, FilterFlag flag) {
    setFilterFlag(flag);
    QSortFilterProxyModel::setFilterRegExp(regExp);
}

bool CustomProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const {
    if(m_lastFilter.isEmpty() || m_cache.contains(source_row))
        return true;
    if(!m_columnPatterns.isEmpty())
        return filterStrings(source_row, source_parent);

    switch(flag) {
    case Int:
        return filterInt(source_row, source_parent);
        break;
    case Double:
        return filterDouble(source_row, source_parent);
        break;
    case LongLong:
        return filterLongLong(source_row, source_parent);
        break;
    case DateTime:
        return filterDateTime(source_row, source_parent);
        break;
    case String:
    case Default:
        return filterString(source_row, source_parent);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent);
}

bool CustomProxyModel::filterStrings(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent)     const {
    if(m_columnPatterns.isEmpty())
        return true;

    bool ret = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < m_columnPatterns.count(); i++)
    {
        int column = m_columnPatterns.keys().at(i);
        QString pattern = m_columnPatterns.value(column).first;
        FilterFlag flag = m_columnPatterns.value(column).second;

        if((flag == String) || (flag == Default))
            ret = filterString(source_row, source_parent, column, pattern);
        else if(flag == Int)
            ret = filterInt(source_row, source_parent, column, pattern);
        else if(flag == Double)
            ret = filterDouble(source_row, source_parent, column, pattern);
        else if(flag == LongLong)
            ret = filterLongLong(source_row, source_parent, column, pattern);
        else if(flag == DateTime)
            ret = filterDateTime(source_row, source_parent, column, pattern);

        if(!ret)
            return ret;
    }

    return ret;
}

bool CustomProxyModel::filterString(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent, int column, QString pattern) const {
    if(column < 0)
        column = filterKeyColumn();
   if(pattern.isEmpty())
        pattern = filterFixedString;

    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(source_row, column, source_parent);
    QString string = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();

    if(pattern.isEmpty())
        return true;
    if(string.contains(pattern, Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        return true;

    return false;
}

bool CustomProxyModel::filterInt(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent, int column, QString pattern) const {
    if(column < 0)
        column = filterKeyColumn();
    if(pattern.isEmpty())
        pattern = filterFixedString;

    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(source_row, column, source_parent);
    bool ok = true;

    int id = sourceModel()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toInt(&ok);
    if(!id)
        return true;

    if(ok) {
        if(id == pattern.toInt())
           return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    return false;
}

bool CustomProxyModel::filterDouble(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent, int column, QString pattern) const {
    if(column < 0)
        column = filterKeyColumn();
    if(pattern.isEmpty())
        pattern = filterFixedString;

    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(source_row, column, source_parent);

    return true;
}

bool CustomProxyModel::filterLongLong(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent, int column, QString pattern) const {
    if(column < 0)
        column = filterKeyColumn();
    if(pattern.isEmpty())
        pattern = filterFixedString;

    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(source_row, column, source_parent);
    bool ok;
    qulonglong id = sourceModel()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toLongLong(&ok);

    if(!ok)
        return false;

    qulonglong filterValue = pattern.toLongLong(&ok);

    if(pattern.isEmpty())
        return true;
    if(!ok)
        return false;

    if(!filterValue)
         return true;
    if(id == filterValue)
        return true;

    return false;
}

bool CustomProxyModel::filterDateTime(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent, int column, QString pattern) const {
    if(column < 0)
        column = filterKeyColumn();
    if(pattern.isEmpty())
        pattern = filterFixedString;

    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(source_row, column, source_parent);

    QString dateTimeString = sourceModel()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();
    QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromString(dateTimeString,    DatabaseManager::getDateTimeFormat());

    return dateTimeInRange(dateTime);
```

}

```
bool CustomProxyModel::dateTimeInRange(const QDateTime &dateTime) const {
    return (!minDateTime.isValid() || dateTime > minDateTime)
                && (!maxDateTime.isValid() || dateTime < maxDateTime);
}

void CustomProxyModel::setFilterMinDateTime(const QDateTime &dateTime)
{
    minDateTime = dateTime;
    invalidateFilter();
}

void CustomProxyModel::setFilterMaxDateTime(const QDateTime &dateTime)
{
     maxDateTime = dateTime;
    invalidateFilter();
}

void CustomProxyModel::recalculateFilter(const QString &str) {
    if(!m_lastFilter.isEmpty() && str.contains(m_lastFilter)) {
        // update the cache by removing items
        for(QSet<int>::iterator iter = m_cache.begin(); iter!=m_cache.end();) {
            QModelIndex idx = sourceModel()->index(*iter, filterKeyColumn());

            if(!idx.data().toString().contains(str))
                m_cache.erase(iter); // remove from cache
            else
                ++iter;
        }
    }
    else if(!m_lastFilter.isEmpty() && m_lastFilter.contains(str)) {
        // update cache by adding items
        for(int i = 0; i < sourceModel()->rowCount(); ++i) {
            if(m_cache.contains(i))
                continue;

            QModelIndex idx = sourceModel()->index(i, filterKeyColumn());

            if(idx.data().toString().contains(str))
                m_cache.insert(i);
        }
    }
    else {
        // recompute everything
        m_cache.clear();
        if(!str.isEmpty()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < sourceModel()->rowCount(); ++i) {
                QModelIndex idx = sourceModel()->index(i, filterKeyColumn());

                if(idx.data().toString().contains(str))
                    m_cache.insert(i);
            }
        }
    }

    m_lastFilter = str;
    //invalidateFilter();
}

void CustomProxyModel::setFilterFlag(FilterFlag flag) {
    this->flag = flag;
}

CustomProxyModel::FilterFlag CustomProxyModel::getFilterFlag() const {
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: 1) Fix your formatting. 2) What do you mean by `but it doesn't seem to be working for me`? 3) What do you mean by `fast`, i.e. what do you mean by `slow` that it currently is? Can you show some benchmarks and why that is crucial?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. I really appreciate it. 1) Sorry, about the formatting. It confuses me. 2) What I mean is that the link gives an example on how to cache searches to make the filtering faster, but I don't see the effect. 3) Well, "fast" in this case, is any duration shorter than 2 seconds. "Slow" is 3 seconds and above. I'm trying to do those "quick searches" in which the user can see the changes as he types the filter text.